# Node.js cannot find module 'connect'

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I already have installed `Node` and `Connect` module for building `HTTP` middlewares.But I keep geeting the following error everytime I try to import `connect` in my `f.js`:

[image]

But I already installed `Connect`:

[image]

Anyone suggest anything?

UPDATE:

my code is as :

```
var connect = require('connect');
var server = connect.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.write("Hello World");
res.end();
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Can you please post your code? Also try `npm install connect` one more time just to be sure it's installed completely.

Comment: sure I'll try @remus

Comment: @remus - I tried, still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your environmental variables pointing to node. 
You can set by right clicking my Computer->properties->Advance System Settings tab->advanced->environment variables. There in the existing PATH variable add the installed node folder location(where node command is working)at the end separated by a semi-colon. Then try node -v from anywhere in your command prompt to verify it gives the version of node installed.
Also verify is there an environment variable for npm
For example DriveLetter:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm

Make sure your f.js and node_modules is in the same folder.

Comment: I tried adding a `Node` variable to my environment variables.And yes, there is one for `npm` too.But no luck :(

Comment: where is your server.js?

Comment: are you able to do command node -v from anywhere in your command prompt or do you have to go the installed directory to make node command work?

Comment: yes I need to go to the installed folder directory to make `node` command work. namely `c:\program files(x86)\nodesjs\node_modules`.

Comment: then environment variable for node is not set properly...see the edited ans...now try again..and do keep me posted

Comment: `node -v` is working properly. But I face the same error.

Comment: the `PATH` variable now includes both for `npm` and `node`

Comment: you didn't answer where is your f.js w.r.t. your app folder structure and node_modules.

Comment: oh! it's in my desktop.

Comment: see the edited answer for correct location of f.js w.r.t. to node_modules.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I think I'm on track.